# Under what circumstances are linked lists useful?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-structures, linked-list

Most times I see people try to use linked lists, it seems to me like a poor (or very poor) choice. Perhaps it would be useful to explore the circumstances under which a linked list is or is not a good choice of data structure.

Ideally, answers would expound on the criteria to use in selecting a data structure, and which data structures are likely to work best under specified circumstances.

Edit: I must say, I'm quite impressed by not only the number, but the quality of answers. I can only accept one, but there are two or three more I'd have to say would have been worth accepting if something a bit better hadn't been there. Only a couple (especially the one I ended up accepting) pointed to situations where a linked list provided a real advantage. I do think Steve Jessop deserves some sort of honorable mention for coming up with not just one, but three different answers, all of which I found quite impressive. Of course, even though it was posted only as a comment, not an answer, I think Neil's blog entry is well worth reading as well -- not only informative, but quite entertaining as well.

Comment: The answer to your second paragraph takes about a semester.

Comment: For my opinion, see http://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/27/letter-the-fourth. And as this seems to be a survey, it should probably be CW.

Comment: @Neil, nice, though I doubt C.S. Lewis would approve.

Comment: @Neil:I guess kind of a survey. Mostly it's an attempt at seeing if anybody can come up with an answer that has a basis I could at least buy as being reasonable. @Seva: yes, rereading it, I made the last sentence a bit more general than I originally intended.

Comment: I'm curious as to whether there are uses in non-pointer-based languages. Or is any hierarchical object tree always a type of linked list?

Comment: @Yar People (including me, I'm sorry to say) used to implement linked lists without pointers in languages like FORTRAN IV (which had no notion of pointers), much as they did trees. You used arrays instead of "real" memory.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I think you will be pleased to hear about your FORTRAN technique. ;-) (Updated answer. Thanks for reminding me. :-)

Comment: [Number crunching: Why you should never, ever, EVER use linked-list in your code again](https://kjellkod.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/why-you-should-never-ever-ever-use-linked-list-in-your-code-again/)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

They can be useful for concurrent data structures. 
(There is now a non-concurrent real-world usage sample below - that would not be there if [**@Neil**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69307/neil-butterworth) hadn't mentioned FORTRAN. ;-)

For example, `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` in .NET 4.0 RC use linked lists to chain items that hash to the same bucket.

The underlying data structure for `ConcurrentStack<T>` is also a linked list.

`ConcurrentStack<T>` is one of the data structures that serve as the foundation for the [new Thread Pool](http://blogs.msdn.com/jennifer/archive/2009/06/26/work-stealing-in-net-4-0.aspx), (with the local "queues" implemented as stacks, essentially). (The other main supporting structure being `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.)

The new Thread Pool in turn provides the basis for the work scheduling of the new 
[Task Parallel Library](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/).

So they can certainly be useful - a linked list is currently serving as one of the main supporting structures of at least one great new technology.

*(A singly-linked list makes a compelling [lock-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-free_and_wait-free_algorithms) - but not wait-free - choice in these cases, because main operations can be carried out with a single [CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) (+retries).
In a modern GC-d environment - such as Java and .NET - the [ABA problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) can easily be avoided. 
Just wrap items you add in freshly created nodes and do not reuse those nodes - let the GC do its work.
The page on the ABA problem also provides the implementation of a lock-free stack - that actually works in .Net (&Java) with a (GC-ed) Node holding the items.)*

**Edit**:
@Neil: 
actually, what you mentioned about FORTRAN reminded me that the same kind of linked lists can be found in probably the most used and abused data structure in .NET: 
the plain .NET generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Not one, but many linked lists are stored in an array.

- It avoids doing many small (de)allocations on inserts/deletes.
- Initial loading of the hash table is pretty fast, because the array is filled sequentially (plays very nice with CPU cache).
- Not to mention that a chaining hash table is expensive in terms of memory - and this "trick" cuts "pointer sizes" in half on x64.

Essentially, many linked lists are stored in an array. (one for each bucket used.)
A free list of reusable nodes is "interwoven" between them (if there were deletes).
An array is allocated at the start/on rehash and nodes of chains are kept in it. There is also a *free* pointer - an index into the array - that follows deletes. ;-) So - believe it or not - the FORTRAN technique still lives on. (...and nowhere else, than in one of the most commonly used .NET data structures ;-).

Comment: In case you have missed, here is Neil's comment: "People (including me, I'm sorry to say) used to implement linked lists without pointers in languages like FORTRAN IV (which had no notion of pointers), much as they did trees. You used arrays instead of "real" memory."

Comment: I should add that the "linked lists in an array" approach in case of the `Dictionary` saves significantly more in .NET: otherwise each node would require a separate object on the heap - and every object allocated on the heap have some overhead. (http://en.csharp-online.net/Common_Type_System%E2%80%94Object_Layout)

Comment: It's also good to know that C++'s default `std::list` is not safe in a multithreaded context without locks.

Answer (score 58):

Linked lists are very useful when you need to do a lot of insertions and removals, but not too much searching, on a list of arbitrary (unknown at compile-time) length.

Splitting and joining (bidirectionally-linked) lists is very efficient.

You can also combine linked lists - e.g. tree structures can be implemented as "vertical" linked lists (parent/child relationships) connecting together horizontal linked lists (siblings).

Using an array based list for these purposes has severe limitations:

- Adding a new item means the array must be reallocated (or you must allocate more space than you need to allow for future growth and reduce the number of reallocations)
- Removing items leaves wasted space or requires a reallocation
- inserting items anywhere except the end involves (possibly reallocating and) copying lots of the data up one position

Comment: So the question reduces to, when *do* you need to do a lot of insertions and removals at the middle of a sequence, but not very many lookups in the list by ordinal? Traversing a linked list is typically as or more expensive than copying an array, so everything you say about removing and inserting items in arrays is just as bad for random-access in lists. LRU cache is one example I can think of, you need to remove at the middle a lot, but you never need to walk the list.

Comment: Adding to a list involves memory allocation for every element you add. This may involve a system call which will be very expensive. Adding to an array only requires such a call if the array must be grown. In fact, in most languages (for exactly these reasons) the array is the preferred data structure and lists are hardly used at all.

Comment: "This may involve a system call" elsewhere you appeared to criticise someone else for assuming a bad array implementation (failed to amortise exponential reallocation). Why now make scary noises about a bad list implementation (fails to use a decent allocation strategy for nodes)? For example in Java, memory allocation is astonishingly fast, much faster than a typical C implementation even once you've accounted for the time cost in Java of GC.

Comment: @Steve I also suggested that such a call *may* be needed for an array.

Comment: So nothing to choose between arrays and lists on that score then - either might require a system call to add an element. Probably with about the same frequency, assuming equivalent growth strategies for both. Sorry, I do mostly agree with you: linked lists and especially `std::list` are pretty rubbish choices almost all the time. I just don't feel anyone is trying to present specific cases for linked lists other than me, it's mostly quite vague "well, if you want the big-O characteristics of a linked list, use a linked list"...

Comment: @Steve I would not like to assume that - presumably as you do assume it you have some figures to back it up?

Comment: Assume which? That allocation is astonishingly fast is evident - usually requires adding the object size to a pointer. That total overhead for GC is low? Last time I tried measuring it on a real app, the key point was that Java was doing all the work when the processor was otherwise idle anyway, so naturally it didn't affect visible performance much. In a busy-CPU benchmark it was easy to upset Java, and get very bad worst case allocation time. This was many years ago, though, and generational garbage collection has markedly reduced the total cost of GC since.

Comment: Anyway, the point wasn't intended to be that malloc/free is typically rubbish (although of course you can't count on it to be good). The point was intended to be that the difference between "requires memory allocation" and "uses a bit of space at the end of an existing array, if there's any left" is, with the right memory allocator, a distinction without a difference. So to say, "lists are rubbish if your memory allocator is rubbish" isn't IMO much of a criticism of lists, since the exact same technique that `std::vector` uses can be used by a list to limit calls to the problematic allocator.

Comment: @Steve: You're wrong about allocation being "the same" between lists and arrays. Each time you need to allocate memory for a list, you simply allocate a small block - O(1). For an array you must allocate a new block large enough for the whole list, and then copy the whole list - O(n). To insert into a known location in a list you update a fixed number of pointers - O(1), but to insert into an array and copy any later items up one position to make room for the insertion - O(n). There are many cases where arrays are therefore much less efficient than LLs.

Comment: @Jason:I think his point was that for an array, you typically grow it in chunks, so you don't do an allocation every time. In fact, you usually grow it geometrically, so complexity of addition is amortized constant.

Comment: @Jerry: I understand. My point is that a large part of the cost of reallocating the array is not *allocating memory*, it is the need to *copy the entire array contents* to the new memory. To insert into item 0 of an array you must *copy the entire array contents* up one position in memory. I'm not saying arrays are bad; just that there are situations where random access is not needed, and where the genuinely constant-time insert/delete/relink of LLs are preferable.

Comment: If you read back, I didn't say they were "the same". I said that they're the same "on that score" (the score being the number of system calls needed for memory allocation, that Neil was worried about) and that they can use "the same technique" (allocating large blocks from the expensive allocator and using them a little at a time). What you do after making the call varies between the two, as you say, but Neil's particular objection to lists in comment 2 of this thread, that I disagreed with, wasn't about that, it was about system calls. Of course there are other objections too.

Answer (score 22):

Linked lists are very flexible: With the modification of one pointer, you can make a massive change, where the same operation would be very inefficient in an array list.

Comment: Would it be possible to motivate why using a list at all and not a set or map?

Answer (score 17):

Arrays are the data structures to which Linked Lists are usually compared.

Normally linked lists are useful when you have to make a lot of modification to the list itself while arrays performs better than lists on direct element access.

Here's a list of operations that can be performed on lists and arrays, compared with the relative operation cost (n = list/array length):

- Adding an element:

  - on lists you just need to allocate memory for the new element and redirecting pointers. O(1)
  - on arrays you have to relocate the array. O(n)
- Removing an element

  - on lists you just redirect pointers. O(1).
  - on arrays you spend O(n) time to relocate the array if the element to remove is not the first or the last element of the array; otherwise you can simply relocate the pointer to the start of the array or decrease the array length
- Getting an element in a known position:

  - on lists you have to walk the list from the first element to the element in the specific position. Worst case: O(n)
  - on arrays you can access the element immediately. O(1)

This is a very low-level comparison of these two popular and basic data structures and you can see that lists performs better in situations where you have to make a lot of modifications to the list it self (removing or adding elements).
On the other hand arrays performs better than lists when you have to access directly the elements of the array.

From the point of view of the memory allocation, lists are better because there's no need to have all the elements next to each others. On the other hand there's the (little) overhead of storing the pointers to the next (or even to the previous) element.

Knowing these differences is important to developers to choose between lists and arrays in their implementations.

Note that this is a comparison of lists and arrays. There are good solutions to the problems here reported (eg: SkipLists, Dynamic Arrays, etc...).
In this answer I've taken into account the basic data structure every programmer should know about.

Comment: This is somewhat true for a good implementation of lists and an awful implementation of arrays. Most array implementations are far more sophisticated than you give them credit for. And I don't think you understand how expensive dynamic memory allocation can be.

Comment: This answer is not supposed to cover the program of a Data Structures University course.
This is a comparison written taking into account Linked lists and arrays, which are implemented the way you, I and most people know.
Geometrically expanding arrays, Skip Lists, etc... are solutions that I know, I use and I study but that would need a deeper explanation and that would not fit a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: "From the point of view of the memory allocation, lists are better because there's no need to have all the elements next to each others." On the contrary, contiguous containers are better *because* they keep the elements next to each other. On modern computers, data locality is king. All that jumping around in memory kills your cache performance, and leads to programs that insert an element at a (effectively) random location performing faster with a dynamic array such as a C++ `std::vector` than with a linked list such as a C++ `std::list`, simply because traversing the list is so expensive.

Comment: @DavidStone Maybe I was not clear enough, but with that sentence I was referring to the fact that you don't need to have contiguous space in order to store your elements. Specifically if you want to store something not too small and you have limited available memory you may not have enough *contiguous free space* to store your data, but you can probably fit your data using a list instead (even though you will have the overhead of pointers... both because of the space they take and the performance problems you mentioned). I should probably update my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

They're useful when you need high-speed push, pop and rotate, and don't mind O(n) indexing.

Comment: Have you ever bothered to time C++ linked lists in comparison with (say) a deque?

Comment: @Neil: Can't say that I have.

Comment: @Neil: if C++ has deliberately sabotaged its linked list class in order to make it slower than any other container (which is not far from the truth), what has that to do with a language-agnostic question? An intrusive linked list is still a linked list.

Comment: @Steve C++ is a language. I can't see how it can have volition. If you are suggesting that members of the C++ Committee somehow sabotaged linked lists (which must logically be slow for many operations), then name the guilty men!

Comment: It's not really sabotage - external list nodes have their advantages, but performance is not one of them. However, surely everyone was aware when making the trade-off of the same thing you're aware of, which is that it's quite difficult to come up with a good use for `std::list`. An intrusive list just doesn't fit with the C++ philosophy of minimum requirements on container elements.

Answer (score 4):

Singly-linked list is a good choice for the free list in a cell allocator or object pool:

1. You only need a stack, so a singly-linked list is sufficient.
2. Everything is divided into nodes already. There is no allocation overhead for an intrusive list node, provided the cells are large enough to contain a pointer.
3. A vector or deque would impose an overhead of one pointer per block. This is significant given that when you first create the heap, all cells are free, so it's an up-front cost. In the worst case it doubles the memory requirement per cell.

Comment: Well, agreed. But how many programmers are actually creating such things? Most are simply re-implementing what std::list etc. give you. And actually "intrusive" normally has  a slightly different meaning than you have given it - that each possible list element contains a pointer separate from the data.

Comment: How many? More than 0, less than a million ;-) Was Jerry's question "give good uses of lists", or "give good uses of lists which every programmer uses on a daily basis", or something in between? I don't know any other name than "intrusive" for a list node which is contained within the object that's a list element - whether as part of a union (in C terms) or not. Point 3 only applies in languages that let you do it - C, C++, assembler good. Java bad.

Answer (score 4):

Doubly-linked list is a good choice to define the ordering of a hashmap which also defines an order on the elements (LinkedHashMap in Java), especially when ordered by last access:

1. More memory overhead than an associated vector or deque (2 pointers instead of 1), but better insert/remove performance.
2. No allocation overhead, since you need a node for a hash entry anyway.
3. Locality of reference is no additional problem compared with a vector or deque of pointers, since you'd have to pull each object into memory either way.

Sure, you can argue about whether an LRU cache is a good idea in the first place, compared with something more sophisticated and tuneable, but if you're going to have one, this is a fairly decent implementation. You do not want to perform a delete-from-middle-and-add-to-the-end on a vector or deque at every read access, but moving a node to the tail is typically fine.

Answer (score 4):

Linked lists are one of the natural choices when you cannot control where your data is stored, but you still need to somehow get from one object to the next.

For example when implementing memory tracking in C++ (new/delete replacement) you either need some control data structure that keeps track of which pointers have been freed, which you fully need to implement yourself. The alternative is to overallocate and add a linked list to the beginning of each data chunk.

Because you always imediately know, where you are in the list when delete is called, you can easily give up memory in O(1). Also adding a new chunk that has just been malloced is in O(1). Walking the list is very rarely needed in this case, so the O(n) cost is not an issue here (walking a structure is O(n) anyway).

Answer (score 4):

One of the most useful cases I find for linked lists working in performance-critical fields like mesh and image processing, physics engines, and raytracing is when using linked lists actually improves locality of reference and reduces heap allocations and sometimes even reduces memory use compared to the straightforward alternatives.

Now that can seem like a complete oxymoron that linked lists could do all that since they're notorious for often doing the opposite, but they have a unique property in that each list node has a fixed size and alignment requirements which we can exploit to allow them to be stored contiguously and removed in constant-time in ways that variable-sized things cannot.

As a result, let's take a case where we want to do the analogical equivalent of storing a variable-length sequence which contains a million nested variable-length sub-sequences. A concrete example is an indexed mesh storing a million polygons (some triangles, some quads, some pentagons, some hexagons, etc) and sometimes polygons are removed from anywhere in the mesh and sometimes polygons are rebuilt to insert a vertex to an existing polygon or remove one. In that case, if we store a million tiny `std::vectors`, then we end up facing a heap allocation for every single vector as well as potentially explosive memory use. A million tiny `SmallVectors` might not suffer this problem as much in common cases, but then their preallocated buffer which isn't separately heap-allocated might still cause explosive memory use.

The problem here is that a million `std::vector` instances would be trying to store a million variable-length things. Variable-length things tend to want a heap allocation since they cannot very effectively be stored contiguously and removed in constant-time (at least in a straightforward way without a very complex allocator) if they didn't store their contents elsewhere on the heap.

If, instead, we do this:

```
struct FaceVertex
{
    // Points to next vertex in polygon or -1
    // if we're at the end of the polygon.
    int next;
    ...
};

struct Polygon
{
     // Points to first vertex in polygon.
    int first_vertex;
    ...
};

struct Mesh
{
    // Stores all the face vertices for all polygons.
    std::vector<FaceVertex> fvs;

    // Stores all the polygons.
    std::vector<Polygon> polys;
};
```

... then we've dramatically reduced the number of heap allocations and cache misses. Instead of requiring a heap allocation and potentially compulsory cache misses for every single polygon we access, we now only require that heap allocation when one of the two vectors stored in the entire mesh exceeds their capacity (an amortized cost). And while the stride to get from one vertex to the next might still cause its share of cache misses, it's still often less than if every single polygon stored a separate dynamic array since the nodes are stored contiguously and there's a probability that a neighboring vertex might be accessed prior to eviction (especially considering that many polygons will add their vertices all at once which makes the lion's share of polygon vertices perfectly contiguous).

Here is another example:

[image]

... where the grid cells are used to accelerate particle-particle collision for, say, 16 million particles moving every single frame. In that particle grid example, using linked lists we can move a particle from one grid cell to another by just changing 3 indices. Erasing from a vector and pushing back to another can be considerably more expensive and introduce more heap allocations. The linked lists also reduce the memory of a cell down to 32-bits. A vector, depending on implementation, can preallocate its dynamic array to the point where it can take 32 bytes for an empty vector. If we have around a million grid cells, that's quite a difference.

... and this is where I find linked lists most useful these days, and I specifically find the "indexed linked list" variety useful since 32-bit indices halve the memory requirements of the links on 64-bit machines and they imply that the nodes are stored contiguously in an array.

Often I also combine them with indexed free lists to allow constant-time removals and insertions anywhere:

[image]

In that case, the `next` index either points to the next free index if the node has been removed or the next used index if the node has not been removed.

And this is the number one use case I find for linked lists these days. When we want to store, say, a million variable-length sub-sequences averaging, say, 4 elements each (but sometimes with elements being removed and added to one of these sub-sequences), the linked list allows us to store 4 million linked list nodes contiguously instead of 1 million containers which are each individually heap-allocated: one giant vector, i.e., not a million small ones.

Answer (score 3):

Singly-linked lists are the obvious implementation of the common "list" data type in functional programming languages:

1. Adding to the head is fast, and `(append (list x) (L))` and `(append (list y) (L))` can share almost all of their data. No need for copy-on-write in a language with no writes. Functional programmers know how to take advantage of this.
2. Adding to the tail is unfortunately slow, but so would be any other implementation.

By comparison, a vector or deque would typically be slow to add at either end, requiring (at least in my example of two distinct appends) that a copy be taken of the entire list (vector), or the index block and the data block being appended to (deque). Actually, there may be something to be said there for deque on large lists which do need to add at the tail for some reason, I'm not sufficiently informed about functional programming to judge.

Answer (score 3):

One example of good usage for a linked list is where the list elements are very large ie. large enough that only one or two can fit in CPU cache at the same time. At this point the advantage that contiguous block containers like vectors or arrays for iteration have is more or less nullified, and a performance advantage may be possible if many insertions and removals are occurring in realtime.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, implementing sparse-matrices and fibonacci heaps. Linked lists give you more control over the overall structure for such data structures. Though I'm not sure if sparse-matrices are best implemented using linked lists - probably there is a better way, but it really helped learning the ins-and-outs of sparse matrices using linked lists in undergrad CS :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two complementary operations which are trivially O(1) on lists and very hard to implement in O(1) in other data structures - removing and inserting an element from arbitrary position, assuming you need to maintain the order of elements.

Hash maps can obviously do insertion and deletion in O(1) but then you cannot iterate over the elements in order.

Given the fact above, hash map can be combined with a linked list to create a nifty LRU cache: A map that stores a fixed number of key-value pairs and drops the least recently accessed key to make room for new ones.

The entries in the hash map need to have pointers to the linked list nodes. When accessing the hash map, the linked list node is unlinked from its current position and moved to the head of the list (O(1), yay for linked lists!). When there's need to remove the least recently used element, the one from the tail of the list needs to be dropped (again O(1) assuming you keep the pointer to the tail node) together with the associated hash map entry (so backlinks from the list to the hash map are necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider that a linked list might be very useful in a Domain Driven Design style implementation of a system that includes parts that interlock with repetition.

An example that comes to mind might be if you were to be modelling a hanging chain. If you wanted to know what the tension on any particular link was, your interface could include a getter for "apparent" weight. The implementation of which would include a link asking its next link for its apparent weight, then adding its own weight to the result. This way, the whole length down to the bottom would be evaluated with a single call from the chain's client.

Being a proponent of code that reads like natural language, I like how this would let the programmer ask a chain link how much weight it's carrying. It also keeps the concern of calculating these kids of properties within the boundary of the link implementation, removing the need for a chain weight calculating service".

Answer (score 1):

Another advantage a linked list has over a contiguous collection is that **a linked list can allocate the object wherever it fits**.
When you have thousands if not millions of objects in contiguous memory, it will become difficult to reallocate the memory - at some point you need twice and more the memory if the contiguous collection needs to reallocate.

With a linked list you have small allocations that can fit in "gaps" of unused memory.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a direct answer to the question, but Python standard implementation of the abstract data type called `deque`  found in `collections.deque` uses a doubly linked list.

Answer (score 0):

I have used linked lists (even doubly linked lists) in the past in a C/C++ application. This was prior to .NET and even stl.

I probably wouldn't use a linked list now in a .NET language because all the traversal code you need is provided for you via the Linq extension methods.