# Linked list and doubly linked list examples

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm looking for a good understandable example in c++ with differences. Does the header file `<list.h>` provide both or should I look somewhere else?

Comment: Examples of _what_?  An example of how to use a linked list?  An example of how a linked list is implemented?  An example of the time and space complexities of using a linked list?

Comment: @Mike Seriously? I think most lists are doubly-linked, it's a pretty small memory overhead in exchange for being able to move backwards

Comment: @Mike:  [There are a few.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429217/under-what-circumstances-are-linked-lists-useful)

Comment: Yes James, Everything :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no `<list.h>`, but is a `<list>` and, I'm afraid, it's not the *"education-purpose code"*. It's an STL implementation of the list which involves iterators and is written to grant maximum flexibility and speed.

You might want to see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) or *Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms"* book for explanation, pseudocode and complexities.

Answer (score 0):

No, thats a double linked list

> list containers are implemented as
>   doubly-linked lists; Doubly linked
>   lists can store each of the elements
>   they contain in different and
>   unrelated storage locations. The
>   ordering is kept by the association to
>   each element of a link to the element
>   preceding it and a link to the element
>   following it.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/