# Dynamic data in c++

Tags: c++

I'm coding in C++ and I'm in need for a dynamic data storage, like ArrayList in C# or Java.

Can anyone help me with that? I'm not sure what to use.
  Thanks!

Comment: [Time to get a good book.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for `std::vector`. You can read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) about it (scroll down on that page to view a description of its functions).

Vectors have constant-time lookup. Insertion/removal is fast at the end of a vector, but (as the link I posted explains in more detail) is slower otherwise. Additionally, vectors have to be resized as you store additional data in them, so it is worth looking into [`reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/) (this is like ArrayLists' `ensureCapacity`). Note that this resizing is automatic - `reserve` is there only for performance reasons.

Answer (score 11):

[std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector` is your friend, [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027) is a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

or `std::list` for that matter...

Comment: If you want an alternative, `std::deque` is probably the second choice for simple dynamic storage. A linked list is the container of choice in only a few, mostly rather unusual, situations. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429217/under-what-circumstances-are-linked-lists-useful

Answer (score 0):

If you're really just a beginner, you should start with the basics: [arrays](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).

Once you understand what's going on underneath, then you should move on to the STL and containers (like `vector`) like everyone else is suggesting.

Comment: I'd say just the opposite: start with vector. At some point in the (probably distant) future, you might have a reason to use an array, but for beginners (and most advanced programmers, for that matter) they're best avoided.

Comment: I think that this is definitely up for debate.  To understand arrays dynamically (and use them safely), it is necessary to understand manual management of memory on a very practical level (pointers, new, delete, referencing, dereferencing, etc..).  One can explain how vectors work with more general/simple concepts, which give a nice introduction to memory management.  I would guess it is for this reason that several of the highly recommended C++ texts (Accelerated C++ and Stroustrup's Programming: Principles and Practice) introduce std::vector long before arrays.

Comment: @Jerry, MarkD: I stand corrected then. In my Comp Sci classes, we were taught arrays, then pointers, then templates, then *barely* touched on STL. The thinking was that once you understood the foundations, you could better understand how to use and work the higher level library. In retrospect though, I really don't agree with a lot that they taught us: my professor *insisted* that I put a `ostream& display(ostream& out) const` method on our static-array `Vector` class, as well as a `friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Type& x) { return x.display(out); }`.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are 2 options that pop out right away.

The first is to use std::vector. A vector works basically the same as an array (except for declaration and calling syntax) on the surface. The 2 things you want to know about vectors is that you can call a function that will increase the size of your vector (add indexes onto the end). The other thing is that to create a 2 dimensional vector you would need to declare a vector of vectors. This also allows you to have more than 2 dimentions.

The other thing you can use is std:: list. This is just a linked list into which you can insert and delete items.

Answer (score 0):

They're both undoubtedly mentioned in the book list, but right about now, it sounds like you need one (or both) of the following:

[*The C++ Standard Library*](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/), by Nicolai Josuttis.
[*STL Tutorial and Reference Guide, 2<sup>nd</sup>ed.*](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/bookseller/product/STL-Tutorial-and-Reference-Guide-C-Programming-with-the-Standard-Template-Library-2E/9780201379235.page), by Musser, Saini, and Derge