# Operations on 1-D array

Tags: c++

How to insert and delete an element of a 1-D array.
for ex:
suppose the array is: 1 3 4 2 5
we want to insert 7 between 3 and 4 so that the new array is: 1 3 7 4 2 5

Answer (score 7):

Use a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) instead of a C-style array.

Use [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/) to insert and [`erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/) to delete elements.

Comment: can you please give me the possible syntax with simple for loops and while loops

Comment: @user451990 - there is a wealth of STL vector iteration example code on this site. Could you track that down rather than requesting a repost here?

Comment: And btw inserting like this gets expensive if your array is large.  Consider std::list in that case (constant-time insert/delete)

Comment: @Steve: That's a list of integers we're talking here. This would have to become _really_ large for a memory move on highly local data to be slower than a `std::list` with its abysmal locality.

Comment: @sbi - yes, for ints this is overkill. However, q refers to inserting into any 1D array, with int as an example.

Comment: @Steve: If in doubt, measure, change, measure again, compare (rinse, repeat). Until then, default to `std::vector` as a first choice.

Comment: @sbi - yes, your prodding drove me to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429217/under-what-circumstances-are-linked-lists-useful

Comment: @Steve: Yes, in theory linked lists are faster than arrays when inserting/removing in the middle. In practice, however, `std::vector` often wins even in such cases (which is usually attributed to the higher locality of its data, which supposedly plays nicer with processor caches). Well, this applies to C++ at least. I don't know whether it also applies to languages that are interpreted and/or feature GC.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays aren't very easy to deal with when you want to insert or remove an element.  You would have to manually copy the data forward by 1 position to insert 1 element to make a new slot available.

To do this with less work to you, you can use an STL vector:

```
#include <vector>

//...

std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(5);
v.insert(v.begin() + 2, 7);
v.erase(v.begin());//Removing the first element just for fun
```

Even with a vector though you are still copying data (just transparently to you).  So to do this most efficiently you would use an `std::list`.

```
#include <list>

//...

std::list<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(5);
v.insert(++(++v.begin()), 7);
v.erase(v.begin());//Removing the first element just for fun
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert elements then using a list would be more appropriate -- arrays are sequential memory blocks so if you want to insert something you have to do work:

```
increase the size of the array
for each element past the spot - move one element further back
write new element at the target position
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with an array in C++ -- you'd have to reallocate the array and move the elements. Use a [`std::vector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xd04bzs(v=VS.80).aspx) instead, and the [`insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5bta5ha(VS.80).aspx) method:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back( 1 );
v.push_back( 3 );
v.push_back( 4 );
v.push_back( 2 );
v.push_back( 5 );

// begin() yields an iterator to the first element; since it's a random-access
// iterator we can offset to insert at index 2.
v.insert( v.begin() + 2, 7 );
```

[`erase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceh559x2(VS.80).aspx) can be used in a similar fashion to remove items.