# difference in implementation of map and dictionary

Tags: .net, c++, data-structures

I know what the difference is in terms of where a map or where a dictionary is used, but what I wondered is why a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in .NET supposedly *uses*, from what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429217/under-what-circumstances-are-linked-lists-useful), a linked list under the covers and I know that a `std::map<K,T>` (C++) is implemented as a red-black tree.

Why aren't they the same under the covers, is there some difference in performance, (which I know that a C++ data structure is optimized for) or why would the .NET dictionary actually be a linked list under the covers and the C++ std::map then a red-black tree, which to my knowledge are *completely different* data structures, used for entirely different purposes mostly.

Perhaps these two things serve a different purpose and maybe I just don't know.

Can anybody clarify?

Comment: The question you linked  to only states that linked lists *are used* in `Dictionary`, not that it *is* a linked list. There's an important difference. :)

Comment: @jalf: hmm interesting point...

Comment: To elaborate on jalf's point, a linked list is one (in my experience often poor) way to handle collisions as hash values for different keys coincidentally fold to the same hash bucket.  In this model, a hash table is effectively an array of linked lists, but the way elements are added, removed, the table resized etc. incorporates the hashing for faster index, and aims to keep each list as short as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Dictionary<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), akin to [`std::unordered_map<>`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/unordered_map/start).

[`SortedDictionary<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) is a red-black tree, akin to [`std::map<>`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/map/start).