# Can't quick sort become stable sort?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

## Approach 1

C.A.R Hoare introduced partitioning logic(shown below), which is taught in school,

```
low = pivot = 0;
i = 1;
j = high = listSize-1;

while (true) {
    while (a[i] <= a[pivot] && (i < high)) {
        i = i + 1;
    }
    while (a[j] >= a[pivot] && (j > low)) {
        j = j - 1; 
    }

    if (i >= j)
        break;
    swap(a[i], a[j])
}

swap(a[j], a[pivot]); // pivot element is positioned(once)
return j;
```

---

## Approach 2

To **basically try  make it stable sort**, Instead `j` pointing to last index(`listSize-1`), if `j` points to `listSize/2`(i.e., `mid`), then,

we get into scenario where  `j > high` or `i >= mid`, where `a[i]` do not have corresponding `a[j]` to swap with and *vice-versa*. In such scenario, swapping `a[i]` with `a[pivot]` also does not make sense, **which looks an incorrect approach**, To confirm the same,

---

My question:

With approach 2,

By maintaining the essence of quick sort, Can't we partition with pivot element(at any index)?

*Note: Analyzing quick sort, not a home work*

Comment: As an aside, my impression is that modifying quicksort to make it stable is likely to sacrifice enough of the *quick* part that you're better off using a naturally stable sort.

Comment: @Hurkyl What does sacrificing *quick* mean?I never thought about meaning of *quick* in this algorithm

Comment: Quick sort is popular because it tends to run faster than other algorithms in its category like merge sort and heapsort. But its advantage is not a huge one -- you can easily lose that advantage if you make quick sort do more work. And I expect the work needed to make quick sort stable is enough to lose the advantage.

Comment: Any sort can be made stable at the cost of using a more complex comparison. If your comprison breaks ties by comparing original indices, the sort will be stable.

Comment: @Hurkyl Quick sort is faster than merge sort, despite 39% more `compare()` in quick sort vis-a-vis mergesort. Because,  less `swap()` operations happen in quicksort. `swap()` is more costly than `compare()` at machine level.

Comment: @overexchange - If stability via quick sort is gained via an array of pointers as answered by chqrlie, then merge sort is faster, because only the pointers are moved, while, the objects are compared through dereferencing of pointers. On a processor with 16 registers, a 4 way merge sort uses 1/2 the moves but 3/2 the compares, and if compares are faster than moves, a 4 way merge sort is faster than quick sort, although the merge sort will need a second array (O(n) space requirement versus quick sort's best case of O(log2(n)) space requirement.

Comment: The relative cost of 'swap' and 'compare' depends on the sort criteria and the data types.  If you're comparing multiple elements of big structures but only swapping pointers to those elements, the cost of compare can be far larger than the cost of swap.  If you're simply comparing and swapping integers, then the comparison is cheaper than the swap.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like home work, so I am not going to solve it completely:

- quick-sort can be made stable by ensuring that no 2 elements compare equal.
- choosing a different pivot alone does not provide a solution for this.

Since you say this is not homework, here is how to make quick-sort stable:

- make an array of pointers to the original array.
- use quick-sort to sort this array with a function that compares the pointed values this way:

  ```
  int sortptr(const void *a, const void *b) {
      const my_type * const *pa = a;
      const my_type * const *pb = b;
      int cmp = original_compare_function(*pa, *pb);
      return cmp ? cmp : (pa > pb) - (pa < pb);
  }
  ```
- copy the sorted items into a sorted array.

Note that this approach can be made to work in place, but it is tricky to do so and would still require allocating the array of pointers. merge-sort is much more reliable for stable sorting, but requires working space of approximately half the size of the original array.

Comment: Query updated. Are you saying that, Quick sort can be stable, if elements are distinct? If yes, that is not the solution to make it stable. Because you are changing the problem to ensure solution to work.

Comment: No, I am saying that the comparison function should not return `0`: if identical elements compare non zero according to their original positions in the array, your sort will be stable.

Comment: @overexchange: your compare function does not implement the trick I mentioned, furthermore, it only works if the original array elements have addresses in strictly increasing order.  In your case, the array is already an array of pointers, but you have no guarantee that the elements satisfy the constraint and you did not implement the comparison function with the extra test.

Comment: I am not relying on address compare(error prone) logic. Am relying on strict value compares, if you see values compares are done before `arraySwap()`

Comment: address compare is not error prone, it is **the** trick required to make quick-sort stable, for elements that compare equal for the value based comparison and if you have the original addresses. I'm afraid you did not understand the method.  Your code already addresses a special case: you sort an array of pointers. if these pointers are allocated in strictly increasing order, you can make `qSort()` stable by comparing the addresses for elements that compare equal for the values.

Comment: I tested your `sortptr()` with keys `2 3 3 1 1`.  After first partition `3` is losing the relative order in with output `1 1 2 3 3`. In this output, last element `3` was at index 1 before partition.

Comment: Did you create an array of pointers to the elements of the array to be sorted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133524/discussion-between-overexchange-and-chqrlie).