# Why Quick sort code is breaking stability?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Below is the `partition()` logic used by `qSort()`,

```
static void qSort(List *list, int low, int high, compareTo compare){

  if(high <= low){
    return; // no partition for sub array of size 1
  }
  int pivotIndex = partition(list, low, high, compare);
  qSort(list, low, pivotIndex-1, compare);
  qSort(list, pivotIndex+1, high, compare);
}

static int partition(List *list, int low, int high, compareTo compare){

  int pivot = low;
  int leftIndex = low + 1;
  int rightIndex = high;
  const void **array = list->array;

  while(true){

    while( leftIndex < high  && (compare(array[leftIndex], array[pivot]) < 0) ){
      leftIndex++;
    } 

    while( rightIndex > pivot && (compare(array[rightIndex], array[pivot])  >  0) ){
      rightIndex--;
    }

    if(leftIndex >= rightIndex){
      break;               // partition is done
    }
    if( compare(array[leftIndex], array[rightIndex]) == 0 ){
      leftIndex++; rightIndex--;
      continue;                   //Maintain stability
    }
    arraySwap(list, leftIndex, rightIndex);
  }
  if( compare(array[pivot], array[rightIndex]) != 0 ){
    arraySwap(list, pivot, rightIndex);           // Maintain stability
  }
  return rightIndex;
}
```

---

where `arraySwap()` && `compare()` is defined as,

```
void arraySwap(List *list, int i, int j){

  const void **array = list->array;

  const void *tempPointer = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = tempPointer;
}

int compare(const void *key, const void *item){

  if( ((Person *)key)->age < ((Person *)item)->age  ){

    return -1;
  }else if( ((Person *)key)->age > ((Person *)item)->age  ){

    return 1;
  }else{

    return 0;
  }
}
```

---

`partition()` has to maintain stability by having extra checks before each `arraySwap()`.

But below output shows that, stability is partially maintained(key `10` is stable unlike key `50`),

```
$ ./sort.exe
Before sorting
Age,LastName,FirstName
  50  B  A
  30  A  B
  20  X  D
  10  F  A
  50  A  B
  90  V  E
  60  N  M
  10  A  B
After sorting

Age,LastName,FirstName
  10  F  A
  10  A  B
  20  X  D
  30  A  B
  50  A  B
  50  B  A
  60  N  M
  90  V  E
```

---

In the `partition()` function, 
below code chunk is to just maintain stability,

```
while(true){
  ....  
  if( compare(array[leftIndex], array[rightIndex]) == 0 ){
    leftIndex++; rightIndex--;
    continue;                        //Maintain stability
  }
  ....
} 
...      
if( compare(array[pivot], array[rightIndex]) != 0 ){ 
  ... 
}
```

---

Question:

Why record with key `50` is not stable?

Answer (score 8):

Quick-sort is unstable because the partition step may swap elements that compare equal to each other, and thus put them in a different order than in the original array.

Making quick-sort stable requires a comparison function that will always return non zero for different elements.

Comment: Query updated with extra description. For your point, *partition step may swap elements that compare equal to each other*, If you see the code, `partiotion()` does not allow `arraySwap()`, when elements are equal. Do you agree?

Comment: OK, I was a bit too precise: the partition step does not swap elements that compare equal, but it may move an element from the left part to the right part, beyond another element that compares equal to it, effectively reversing their order in the array, and vice-versa.

Comment: Equal to it, you mean `size =1` sub array? am not partitioning `size =1` sub array. Updated query. Probably i did not get your comment.

Comment: @overexchange: no. Let's take a simple example: the array contains `A1 D1 C D2 A2`, pivot is `C`, the partition step will swap `D1` and `A2`, effectively reversing the order of the `D1` and `D2` entries.

Answer (score 4):

Avoiding swapping equal elements is not by any means sufficient to achieve a stable quicksort.  Consider, for example, this simple case:

```
key  value
2    A
3    B
3    C
1    D
1    E
```

Taking the first element as the pivot, the first partitioning involves three swaps: (1, 4) and (2, 3) in the main part of the partitioning, then (0, 2) to put the pivot in place.  That yields:

```
1   D
1   E
2   A
3   C
3   B
```

No elements having equal keys were swapped, but the relative order of the two items with key `3` was reversed.  This happens naturally, at both ends of the partition, as a result of the upper half of the array being traversed in reverse order.

Additionally, you have an opportunity for instability when you swap the pivot element into place.  Since it starts at the far left of the array, if there are any other elements with the same key that end up in the left partition, but the element at the extreme right end of the left partition has a different key, then the partition element will be moved relative to others having the same key.

To be sure of a stable sort, the comparison function must take the original element order into account.  That would usually require using O(N) additional metadata.  It would be fair to interpret this as saying that quicksort cannot be made stable at all, since incorporating the original element order into the comparison function effectively makes all elements unequal, and the question of stability therefore moot.

Comment: So code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41715969/3317808)  shouldn't work in that case

Comment: My understanding is,  **1)** this answer about losing relative position holds good for any unstable sort. **2)** Instead of swap() if smallest element after compare() is copied to aux array, then this instability should not have occured, which is nothing but `merge()` operation of `mergeSort()`

Comment: @overexchange, the other answer to which you link does precisely what I describe being necessary, in a rather clever way.  I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @overexchange, (1) perhaps this answer could be extended to, or similar arguments made about, other unstable sorts, but as it stands, it is specific to the details of quicksort.  (2) I'm not sure I completely follow the variation you describe, but to the extent that I do follow it, it seems to me that the result is no longer a quicksort, and it does not have the same properties as quicksort (e.g. space complexity).

Comment: @overexchange, I should clarify: my explanation for why quicksort cannot be made stable is specific to quicksort.  My suggestion for how to achieve a stablely-sorted result from an unstable sorting algorithm, on the other hand, is general.  You could reasonably describe the latter as changing the nature of the data so that it is unaffected by the instability of the algorithm.